# Replace {{xxx}} with %s

Tags: java, string, replace

How to replace `{{......}}` with `%s` in the following sentence?

```
String str="Your appointment with {{provider_name}} on {{start_time}} is cancelled at {{careCenter_name}}. Call {{careCenter_phoneNumber}} for queries.";
```

the result should be this:

```
Your appointment with %s on %s is cancelled at %s. Call %s for queries.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) or [String.replaceFirst()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex with `String.replaceAll()` method :

```
str.replaceAll("\\{\\{.+?\\}\\}", "%s")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str="Your appointment with {{provider_name}} on {{start_time}} is cancelled at {{careCenter_name}}. Call {{careCenter_phoneNumber}} for queries.";
    String reg="(?:\\{\\{([\\w_-]+)\\}\\})";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(reg);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while(m.find()){
        str = str.replace(m.group(0), "%s");
    }
    System.out.println(str);
```

you can use m.group(1) when you want to deal with actual values wrapped in two curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex:-

```
String s = "Your appointment with {{provider_name}} on {{start_time}}";
s = s.replaceAll("\\{.*?\\}\\}", "%s");
```

Output:-
Your appointment with %s on %s